# asp.net / sql user.identity.name

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to get a details view in ASP.NET to display the details of the logged-in user only. I have been told to use:

```
select * from STAFF where USERNAME = user.identity.name
```

I thought this was too simple to be true and I was correct as it shows no data when I attempt to run. Any help with this please..

Comment: What type of authentication are you using? Are you using the .net Membership Provider. Is it hooked into Active Directory or is it forms authentication? What type of database are you using? The best way to find out is by looking in your database and check if the aspnet_xxxx tables are present. If not then I don't have much to go on.

Comment: using an SQL database, the asp.net_xxxx tables are present and using form authentication.

Comment: I don't think they meant to use the literal string `user.identity.name`.  I think they meant construct a SQL statement where USERNAME is equal to the value of the `User.Identity.Name` property for the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently tried to do the same. It was too much headache for what I wanted to do so I ended up building the form from scratch. If you want to use the details view you can call the

aspnet_Membership_GetUserByName or
aspnet_Membership_GetUserByEmail or
aspnet_Membership_GetUserByUserId

and populate a DataTable or DataSet with the results and DataBind it to your DetailsView. However, if you can avoid using the DetailsView for this I would recommend it because you're circumventing the Membership provider which totally defeats the purposes of having it in the first place.

Try extending the `SqlMembershipProvide`r by creating a `CustomMembershipProvider` and override and overload the `GetUser()` method to return a `DataTable` that can easily bound to the Details View.

It would look something like this>

```
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data;

namespace yourNameSpace
{

    public class CustomSqlMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
    {


        public override MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)
        {
            return base.GetUser(providerUserKey, userIsOnline);
        }

        public DataTable GetUser(string UserName)
        {
            MembershipUser user = base.GetUser(username, false);

            //code to create a datatable and populate it with user properties.
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            //Add columns
            DataColumn column = new DataColumn();

            //add columns to table

            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you reference your new membership provider in your web.config when you're done.

Help this gives you some direction. It requires some work but in the end it's easier to maintain then troubleshooting any membership circumventing code.